# mysqldump insert data to exists table

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

hellow

Dumped x.sql file from db and then 
trying  to find way to insert data from x.sql file to existent tbl in another server.
But mysql execute all the concept of the x.sql ( that include "drop table if exists tbl and create new")

mysql --host= --user= --password= schema tbl < x.sql

there is away may be to dump tbl (with out "drop and create new" commands only insert )?

Comment: how and what x.sql contain are quite important. How was it generated? Is it exactly the same table structure? What statements does it contain? Can you edit the file to remove the `drop table` and `create table`? Are you likely to have duplicate rows on the primary / unique key?

Comment: Restore it into separate (temporarily created) database, than join data using simple INSERT query.

Comment: @danblack from server x table tbl used mysqldump --where id > x . then to server y import data mysql --host= --user= --password= schema tbl < x.sql . but it drop tbl on server y and create the same tbl

Answer (score 1):

If you can rebuild the x.sql, run `mysqldump` with suitable option such as `--no-drop-tables`, `--no-creates` (or whatever they are).  Then look at the dump file to make sure there are no surprises in it.

If you can't rebuild `x.sql`, then edit it to get rid of drops/creates/etc.

If there are no `USE` statements in `x.sql`, you can say `mysql ... new_db < x.sql` (after doing `CREATE DATABASE new_sql`).  Then play SQL games to copy the data from `new_db.foo` to `old_db.foo`.  (Provide more details if you need help in this area.)